# Doing a calculation in sql without sum

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have this table that I generated from sql using an inner join, now I want to calculate the total cost of each order_id, for example the screen shot shows 4 orders for order id 127, I want to combine the total costs of each ordered item by 127 into one number, same for the other order ids.
my price is in another table which I haven't specified in this query.

I was thinking of doing something like quantity* price, but I am not sure how to link that to the order ids like i've mentioned above.

many thanks for your help:)

sql:

```
select P.carrier_id, O.aircraft_id, O.order_id, O.quantity 
from orderline O 
inner join purchaseorder P on O.order_id = P.order_id;
```

My results so far:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the SQL that generated that query, or explain how the tables are set up?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the other table? Also, please do it in text rather than a picture - just do this at the SQLPlus prompt: `SPOOL stru.txt` `DESC yourtablename` `SPOOL OFF` `edit stru.txt`. Then copy and paste the stru.txt content here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use `group by`. I need to know the rest of your query to give you a complete version, but - roughly:

```
select P.carrier_id, O.aircraft_id, O.order_id, sum(O.quantity) -- columns
from orderline O 
inner join purchaseorder P on O.order_id = P.order_id -- tables and join
group by  P.carrier_id, O.aircraft_id, O.order_id;
```

You might think you just need to group by order id, but the rule of thumb is actually "group by everything that you're not counting (or summing...)

Also, as pointed out by the other answer, if you have a record of prices, you can do `sum(O.quantity*P.price)` or something close to that to obtain the total price of each order.

Comment: just to get the table I have I used : select P.carrier_id, O.aircraft_id, O.order_id, O.quantity from orderline O inner join purchaseorder P on O.order_id = P.order_id;

Comment: Great thanks a lot, managed to get it to work, used my inner join and then after defined how the price of the products would match the order ids in my tables, using the where statement. thats alot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `GROUP BY` on `ORDER_ID`, `AIRCRAFT_ID`, then do a `SUM(quantity * price)`